# Android Studio - getLocationOnScreen

Tags: android

why there ist no counterpart to getLocationOnScreen? The intuitive way would be setLocationOnScreen... I have an Image View and want to get these coordinates to give the same coordinates to another Image View.

The mentioned intuitive way would be:

```
int [] location = new int [2];
imageView1.getLocationOnScreen(location);
imageView2.setLocationOnScreen(location);
```

But this set command is not available. This would be the easiest thing :( Is there any counterpart?

PS: my Image has no margins...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Because position on screen is controlled by the layout that the ImageView is in, not the ImageView itself. If you need a layout that allows you to position subviews at specific coordinates, try a FrameLayout.

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is deprecated, use FrameLayout instead